# Click trigger causing infinite loop

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, eventtrigger

```
var active=-1;
jQuery('.next').click(function(event){
    if (active < 0){
        active = jQuery('ul#checkout_timeline').find('li.active').data('step');
       //alert(active);
    }
    if(active == '1'){   
        active = 0 
        jQuery(".next").trigger("click");        
        active = jQuery('ul#checkout_timeline').find('li.active').data('step')+1;
        return false;
    }
```

I want to perform a trigger 2 times so that I can skip 2 steps and land on 4th one. How can I archieve that?

Comment: give `jQuery(".next").trigger("click").addClass("active");` assuming that you are triggering click on the `li` element or instead of  `active =jQuery('ul#checkout_timeline').find('li.active').data('step')+1;` you can give ` active =jQuery('ul#checkout_timeline').find('li.active').data('step')+2;`

Comment: your reseting the `active` variable, remove `active = 0`, otherwise the condition `active == '1'` will be met

Comment: @claudio if i am removing active = 0 i will be getting an infinite loop

Comment: @AswinRamesh the trigger is activated while clicking on next button (".next")

Comment: @Jackson that's because `active` is not changing, what about making `active = 2`?

Comment: @claudio nothing specifically happened

Comment: @Jacksoncan you try by changing the `active =jQuery('ul#checkout_timeline').find('li.active').data('step')+1;` to `active =jQuery('ul#checkout_timeline').find('li.active').data('step')+2;`

Comment: @AswinRamesh i tried doing it but nothings seems to work